# ¿Cómo guardar los valores de las variables en un archivo?

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cuando mande las variables con sus respectivos valores el `console.writeline` los lea y los guarde al respectivo archivo creado, cuando comienza a guardar la información, solo guarda la primera variable pero no las dos.

```
Console.Title = "decrypter zRIF - Allysson jesus";
Console.WriteLine("\t creador de batch para zRIF.");
Console.WriteLine("\nDigite el zRIF de la app/juego: ");
TextWriter archivo;

archivo = new StreamWriter("convert.bat");

string zRIF;
string code_bat ="pkg2zip -x package.pkg ";

zRIF = Console.ReadLine();
code_bat = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine($"{code_bat} {zRIF}");
archivo.Close();

Console.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("Esta hecho...");

Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: codigo]

Comment: Por favor incluye el código (estoy en una red privada y no puedo ver imágenes de ese servidor).

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe estar como texto y no como imagenes. A que variables te refieres?

Comment: ya esta agregado

Comment: a las variables "code_bat" y "zRIF"

Comment: ¡Mucho mejor! Ahora bien, ¿exactamente cuál es el problema? Ahí puedo ver que estás leyendo algo desde la consola y... ya, tienes un archivo preparado pero no veo que lo afectes. ¿Quieres escribir esa línea en el archivo?

Comment: En el caso de la variable "code_bat", ya tiene algo almacenado, pero en el caso de "zRIF" no , quisiera que cuando el usuario digite algo se guarde en "zRIF" y que al final las dos variables escriban su informacion en una sola linea dentro de lo que es el archivo ya creado previamente.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, solo te falta usar el objeto `StreamWriter` para escribir en el archivo. Te dejo tu ejemplo completado:

```
        Console.Title = "decrypter zRIF - Allysson jesus";
        Console.WriteLine("\t creador de batch para zRIF.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nDigite el zRIF de la app/juego: ");

        string zRIF;
        string code_bat = "pkg2zip -x package.pkg ";

        zRIF = Console.ReadLine();

        var text = $"{code_bat} {zRIF}";


        using (StreamWriter archivo = new StreamWriter("convert.bat"))
        {

            archivo.WriteLine(text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Esta hecho...");

        Console.ReadKey();
```